# Deleting migration folder "No migrations to apply"

Tags: django, heroku

I have deleted migration folder because I have an issue which can't to solve. After that I try to migrate, but it wrotes me "No migrations to apply".
[image]

So, I don't understand why it wrote me this message, when I don't migrate these files.

Comment: If you deleted your migrations folder, which migrations are you expecting to be run ?

Comment: Deleting your migrations folder is about as wrong a "solution" as there is. Restore it, then ask about the actual issue you were having. This is a clear [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).

Answer (score 1):

Command `python manage.py migrate` seeks the migration files and then try to rebuild database according to that files. If you have deleted those files there is nothing to read/compare.

If you have deleted those files you might need to drop database and create new one unless you try `makemigrations`. But probably it will raise some errors if you made some important changes in model structures.

Answer (score 1):

Run this command

```py
   python manage.py showmigrations
```

This migration looks like
`[X] 0001_migration_filename.py`
`[X]` which means migration is not deleted. so you need to delete migration from the database as well. if you are using sqllite3(by default database) then delete the `.sql` file or if you are using PostgreSQL or any other database then delete the migration file from the django_migration database.